Problema de Web Scraping
NO recoge ninguna información de algún producto.
Este código consiste en recoger 3 productos diferentes de 3 paginas web o supermercados (Éxito, Carulla y Jumbo) se utilizó las librerías de Pandas, BeautifulSoup y Requests, además de mostrar los resultados por csv, lo que pasa es que no funciona la extracción de información por medio de las clases de cada producto en el código de HTML en las páginas web.
Ejemplo: el producto en el código HTML esta así:
<h1 class="product-title_product-title__heading___mpLA">Sal  REFISAL Refinada (1000  gr)</h1>

El código completo es:
```import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

keywords = ["Sal REFISAL Refinada (1000 gr)", "Sal Refisal bolsa x1000g", "Bebida Hidratante GATORADE Frutas Tropicales (500 ml)", "Bebida Hidratante GATORADE Frutas Tropicales (500 ml)", "Gatorade Frutas Tropicales pet x500ml","Arroz DIANA (3000 gr)", ""]


# Función para extraer datos de una página web
def extract_data(url, product_tags, price_tags, keywords):
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        products = [prod.get_text(strip=True) for prod in soup.find_all(*product_tags)]
        prices = [price.get_text(strip=True) for price in soup.find_all(*price_tags)]

        # Filtrar los productos y precios que contienen las palabras clave
        filtered_products = []
        filtered_prices = []

        for keyword in keywords:
            found = False
            for product, price in zip(products, prices):
                if keyword.lower() in product.lower():
                    filtered_products.append(product)
                    filtered_prices.append(price)
                    found = True
                    break
            if not found:
                filtered_products.append("No disponible")
                filtered_prices.append("0")

        # Convertir los precios a float, reemplazando "No disponible" por 0.0
        clean_prices = [float(price.replace('$', '').replace(',', '').strip()) if price != "0" else 0.0 for price in filtered_prices]
        return filtered_products, clean_prices
    else:
        print(f"Error al acceder a {url}")
        return ["No disponible"] * len(keywords), [0.0] * len(keywords)

# URLs de Carulla, Éxito y Jumbo
url1 = "https://www.carulla.com/?srsltid=AfmBOoq71oAH_TAlUAMVPf1DnaRm_THxKZOI0pBcjkbDcKcQA_IW2-7R"
url2 = "https://www.exito.com"
url3 = "https://www.tiendasjumbo.co/?gad_source=1&gclid=Cj0KCQjwyL24BhCtARIsALo0fSC-mbP_2f2_jBdm8AKpyimjv7jz7G-EElfKoVB0GdQfZwahx2t6CqUaAkiOEALw_wcB"

# Selectores HTML específicos para Carulla, Éxito y Jumbo
product_tags1C = ('h1', 'vtex-store-components-3-x-productNameContainer mv0 t-heading-4')  # Producto Sal Carulla: 
price_tags1C = ('div', 'exito-vtex-components-4-x-PricePDP')   # Precio Sal Carulla

product_tags1E = ('h1', 'product-title_product-title__heading___mpLA')  # Producto Sal Exito
price_tags1E = ('p', 'ProductPrice_container__price__XmMWA')         # Precio Sal Exito`introducir el código aquí`

product_tags1J = ('span', 'vtex-store-components-3-x-productBrand')  # Producto Sal Jumbo
price_tags1J = ('div', 'tiendasjumboqaio-jumbo-minicart-2-x-price')          # Precio Sal Jumbo



# Palabras clave de los productos a buscar
keywords = ["REFISAL 1000 GR", "GATORADE FRUTOS ROJOS 500ML", "ARROZ DIANA 3KG"]

# Extraer productos y precios de las tres páginas
products1, prices1 = extract_data(url1, product_tags1C, price_tags1C, keywords)
products2, prices2 = extract_data(url2, product_tags1E, price_tags1E, keywords)
products3, prices3 = extract_data(url3, product_tags1J, price_tags1J, keywords)

# Organizar los datos en un DataFrame para comparar
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Producto Carulla': products1,
    'Precio Carulla': prices1,
    'Producto Éxito': products2,
    'Precio Éxito': prices2,
    'Producto Jumbo': products3,
    'Precio Jumbo': prices3
})

# Calcular el precio mínimo y máximo por producto
df['Precio Minimo'] = df[['Precio Carulla', 'Precio Éxito', 'Precio Jumbo']].min(axis=1)
df['Precio Maximo'] = df[['Precio Carulla', 'Precio Éxito', 'Precio Jumbo']].max(axis=1)

# Encontrar el producto más barato y más caro en general
producto_mas_barato = df.loc[df['Precio Minimo'].idxmin()]
producto_mas_caro = df.loc[df['Precio Maximo'].idxmax()]

# Mostrar la comparación de precios y los productos más baratos y más caros
print("\nComparación de precios entre Carulla, Éxito y Jumbo:\n", df)
print("\nProducto más barato:\n", producto_mas_barato[['Producto Carulla', 'Precio Minimo']])
print("\nProducto más caro:\n", producto_mas_caro[['Producto Carulla', 'Precio Maximo']])

# Guardar los datos en un archivo CSV
df.to_csv('comparacion_precios_productos_especificos.csv', index=False)```

Me gustaría saber si toca indexarlo de otra forma o si de verdad estoy extrayendo los datos de mala forma. GRACIAS POR LA AYUDA
